# Saving multiple selected tableViewCells with custom Objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'mc creating a UITableViewController, which contains a list of teams. These can all be selected using the accessoryView which can be seen at the below image. The idea is that every time you select a cell it will add the specific Team Object from (custom class) fromt he teamArray to the teamSelected array and when you select again it will remove it. This worked fine at the beginning when i was comparing `(value == team)` however when i returned to the viewController and loaded the teamSelected from the NSUserDefaults it did not marked them with `cell.accessoryCheck`. I found out the reason to this is that the objects changes every time i enter this TableViewController and load the teamObjects from a JSON file. Therefor i decided to go with `(value.id == team.id)` Where the id is a unique id for each team. This worked and now it is marking them correctly with `cell.accessoryCheck`. However now it does not seem to remove the selected team Object from teamSelected? it just return that its out of range?

Illustration of my view

[image]

Here is my code:

My arrays

```
var teamArray = Array<Team>()
var teamSelected = [Team]()
```

Custom team Object

```
class Team: NSObject{
var id: Int!
var name: NSString!
var shortname: NSString!


init(id: Int, name:NSString, shortname: NSString) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.shortname = shortname

}


required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("id")
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    let shortname = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("shortname") as! String
    self.init(id: id, name: name, shortname: shortname)
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encodeObject(shortname, forKey: "shortname")
}


}
```

In viewDidLoad

```
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let data = userDefaults.objectForKey("teams") as? NSData {
        let teamObjects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)  as! [Team]
        self.teamSelected = teamObjects
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("teamCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    if (self.teamSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row].name

    } else {

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.teamArray[indexPath.row].name as String

    }


    let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
    var removed = false

    for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
        if (value.id == team.id) {


            cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryCheck
            removed = true
        }
    }

    if (!removed) {
        cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryUncheck

    }



    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
    var removed = false



    for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
        if (value.id == team.id) {
            self.teamSelected.removeAtIndex(index)
            removed = true
        }
    }

    if (!removed) {
        self.teamSelected.append(team)
    }

     var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.teamSelected)
    userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "teams")
    userDefaults.synchronize()





    tableView.reloadData()
}
```